# Switch case issue in objective C

Tags: ios, switch-statement

This is the code I followed up on a tutorial

```
- (UIColor *) randomColor {
int rand = arc4random_uniform(5);
NSLog(@"Num is %d",rand);
switch(rand){
    case 1 : return [UIColor greenColor];
    case 2 : return [UIColor blueColor];
    case 3 : return [UIColor orangeColor];
    case 4 : return [UIColor purpleColor];

}
return [UIColor blackColor];

}
```

This was the exact code in the tutorial and as far as I know, if a switch statement does not have a break statement it should fall through and should execute all the cases, but it does not seem to happen, it just breaks out by itself. Is it because of UIColor or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return` [keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sta56yeb.aspx) ends the execution of a function, so your function ends the first case it enters (because you have `return` in every case)

A quick fix:

```
- (UIColor *) randomColor {
int rand = arc4random_uniform(5);
NSLog(@"Num is %d",rand);

UIColor* colorToReturn;

switch(rand){
    case 1 : colorToReturn= [UIColor greenColor];
    case 2 : colorToReturn=[UIColor blueColor];
    case 3 : colorToReturn=[UIColor orangeColor];
    case 4 : colorToReturn=[UIColor purpleColor];

}

return colorToReturn;

}
```

Comment: Oh, If thats the case then why would it show an error when i tried to move the return [UIColor blackColor] as Case 0 in my switch case? It should just exit the function in that case? (Cause technically the random number is generated from 0..4)

Comment: If you moved it altogether (cut and copied) then probably you received a compiler error that the function doesn't return a value. If you move the `return` to `case 0` then it will return only if `rand === 0`, otherwise, the function will have no return value - hence the compiler warning.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement makes the function stop executing. So, if `int rand = 1`, it will just return the `[UIColor greenColor]` and the function will stop. Here's the proper code :

```
- (UIColor *)randomColor {
  int rand = arc4random_uniform(5);
  UIColor *color;
  switch(rand) {
    case 1 : color = [UIColor greenColor];
    case 2 : color = [UIColor blueColor];
    case 3 : color = [UIColor orangeColor];
    case 4 : color = [UIColor purpleColor];
    default : color = [UIColor blackColor];
  }

  return color;
}
```